# How to get around a "Route not found" 404?

Tags: coinbase-api

I'm following the Coinbase API docs (https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2?shell#notification-resource) to hit their endpoints, but some cURL requests work and some don't.

For example, if I query https://api.pro.coinbase.com/user, it fails. If I query https://api.pro.coinbase.com/accounts, it successfully lists all of my accounts.

(Also, it seems like things work if I leave the "/v2" out of the URL for some reason)

(Also, it seem like the URL with the "pro" in it works where without it just fails. Another oddity.)

I'm not seeing any other issues (bad API key, malformed signature, etc.). In fact, the response code I get back from the cURL command is a 404, which suggests that Coinbase couldn't even find that URL (with or without the "/v2").

Anybody else noticed this and been able to address it?

Comment: "if I query https://api.pro.coinbase.com/user, it fails." -- I get unauthorized for both, not 404 for either. How exactly does it fail?

Comment: It returns: "public 'message' => string 'Route not found'"

The HTTP response code it returns is: 404

You'll get unauthorized if you don't provide approrpriate credentials as part of the request, but I'm past that. My credentials are good, my request body is well-formed, my signature is correct, etc. It just fails when the request is made to "/user" but not other things like "/accounts". It's really weird.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [PRO (now Exchange) API docs](https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/exchange/reference/exchangerestapi_getuserexchangelimits) there is no `user` endpoint, just `users`, and that's just to get the exchange limits.

```
https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/users/{user_id}/exchange-limits
```

it looks like the user endpoint falls under the [Coinbase API](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2?shell#show-a-user)

```
https://api.coinbase.com/v2/user
```

Comment: That's part of the frustration; they seem to be crossed-linked. I can set up an OAuth with Coinbase and the "/user" endpoint now works, but you can't use the OAuth on Pro, only an API key... and the Coinbase API lets you buy into your Coinbase account with no API to move the funds to Coinbase Pro... and all of this before factoring in Exchange.Coinbase.com.

It's an absolute pain.

I can now call an endpoint with an OAuth, but the exact same endpoint with a cURL call gives me a 404. It's just... crap.